# How to parse `key1:val1,val2,val3,key2:val1,val2` in python?

Tags: python-2.7

Given a str as `key1:val1,val2,val3,key2:val11,val22`, what is the most efficient way to split the string as follows:

```
key1: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
key2: ['val11', 'val22']
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Fast, memory efficient, readable?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [150]: answer = {}

In [151]: s = "key1:val1,val2,val3,key2:val11,val22"

In [152]: for pair in s.split(','):
    k, _, v = pair.rpartition(":")
    if k: key = k
    if key not in answer: answer[key] = []
    answer[key].append(v)
   .....:     

In [153]: for k,vals in answer.items():
    print(k, ":", vals)
   .....:     
key2 : ['val11', 'val22']
key1 : ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```